# Unexpected end of JSON input when sending data via ajax

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/xot/us/confirm",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType : 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data:JSON.stringify({
      username:"User"
    }),
    success: function(result, status, xhr) {
      console.log(result.address1);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: So the error is coming from the serverside or the clientside? Cross domain call so you have CORS enabled? `crossDomain: true,` is typically JSONP

Comment: Please ask a question, do not just post code

Comment: The data is either badly formed JSON or not JSON at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using nodejs as a backend you should add header there

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
);
next();  
});
```

And in Ajax Request .. Your request looks will look like this

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:3002/category",
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data:JSON.stringify({
    username:"User"
    }),
    success: function(result, status, xhr) {
    console.log(result);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log(error);
    }
    })
```

Comment: This still doesnt work....When i send some data to backend in json format...It shows the same error.No problem in CORS.